# Pyinstaller and Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pyinstaller

I am trying to use Pyinstaller with django rest, it generates the .exe well but there is an error at the moment of executing the .exe, the error is this

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
```

my question is how can I install the dependencies using Pyinstaller, or is there another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error ocurrs when you have dynamic imports in your code. In that case, pyinstaller don't include those packages in exe file. In that case you can:

1. Add unused import of those packages in your code
2. [Tell pyinstaller to include it](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports)

One file option does not change anything in running your code. If you're create --onefile exe all files created by pyinstaller are packed to exe file, and unpacked to local temp every time when you run exe.

Other Possible Solutions are:

Solution 1:
run your command from parent directory, i.e. instead of

```
c:\compilation\Gui>pyinstaller --name=gui manage.py
```

do

```
c:\compilation>pyinstaller --name=gui Gui\manage.py
```

Also Add runserver to the End of the File.

if still the Issue Persists, Then
Solution 2: 
    pyinstaller --name=gui --exclude-module=PyQt4 --exclude-module=matplotlib --clean --win-private-assemblies manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the required modules installed correctly. 
After you have installed the required modules, create hook for rest_framework and add it to ..\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks and name the file as hook-rest_framework.py. Contents of file:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('rest_framework')
```

This solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

in your manage.spec file, you need add such code below:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules

hiddenimports = collect_submodules('rest_framework')
```

and also you need add another Dependency packages

```
hiddenimports.extend(
    [
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'django_filters',
        ....
    ]
)
```

and if you rest-freamwork template shows doesn't exist, so you need config the static files as blew；

```
datas=[(r'/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/', './rest_framework'),               
(r'/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_filters/', './django_filters')
]
```

Answer (score -2):

In your terminal:

```
pip install djangorestframework
pip install markdown
pip install django-filter
```

python3 can use pip3 install.